# Does this sequence $\,\sqrt[n]{1+\cos2n}\,$ have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

Does this
$\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1+\cos2n}\,$ exist?

It took me and my tutor 2 days to find this limit. We believe that this function has no limit or if it does, we are not intellectual enough to find it. Hope someone can help us.

Comment: Hint:-$\cos(2n)=\cos^{2}(n)-\sin^{2}(n)$

Comment: Is $n\in \mathbb{N}$? If not, $\liminf \sqrt[n]{1+\cos2n}=0$ since the subsequence $(\pi m -\frac{1}{2} \pi)_{m\in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence of roots of the function

Comment: Well, I can prove that if the limit exists then it equals to $2$. Let me know if someone can prove the existence of the limit.

Comment: @RAHUL [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/80j7c6kikm) makes it seem like the limit should be $1$.

Comment: @podiki, yaa you are right. It was my computational mistake, the limit is $1$. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 25):

Answer:
$$
\sqrt[n]{1+\cos(2n)}\to 1.
$$

This is due to the fact that the [irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) $\mu$ of $\pi$ is a finite number (approx. 7.1032), i.e., for every $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\left|\pi -\frac{p}{q}\right|\ge \frac{1}{q^{\mu+\varepsilon}},
$$
for all but finitely many rationals $p/q$.

This implies that if $2n$ is very close to some $(2k+1)\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb N$, then
$$
1+\cos(2n)=2\cos^2(n)=2\sin^2\big(n-(k+\tfrac{1}{2})\pi\big)
\ge \frac{8}{\pi^2}\big(n-(k+\tfrac{1}{2})\pi\big)^2
\\ =\frac{2(2k+1)^2}{\pi^2}\Big(\frac{2n}{2k+1}-\pi\Big)^2\ge \frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)^{2(\mu-1+\varepsilon)}}
\approx \frac{c}{n^{2(\mu-1+\varepsilon)}}
$$
for some $c>0$. Note that the first inequality above is due to the fact that
$$
\sin x>\frac{2x}{\pi}, \quad x\in (0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}).
$$
So
$$
\sqrt[n]{2}\ge \sqrt[n]{1+\cos(2n)}\ge
\sqrt[n]{\frac{c}{n^{2(\mu-1+\varepsilon)}}}
$$
and hence $\sqrt[n]{1+\cos(2n)}\to 1$.

Comment: Great answer! I was aware of this inequality for quadratic irrationals - this extension to transcendentals is just what I was looking for!

Comment: Very nice answer. I think you might have dropped a factor of $(2k+1)^2$ in the equality between inequalities, but it shouldn't change much.

Comment: Technically you've quoted an approximate upper bound on $\mu(\pi)$, but its being even lower wouldn't affect this argument.

Comment: Minor comment: The value $7.1032$ is an *upper bound* for the irrationality measure. We do not know the precise irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Comment: thank you so much !

Comment: Then, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1529245/721644) might be related?